# client cant connect to openVPN with static_ip

Tags: openvpn

I configure vpn server base on this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04), my server has a static ip v4 and i set in client.conf, but user cant connect to vpn in windows app and error :

```
trasmitting bypass route to STATIC_IP
{
"host":"STATIC_IP",
"ipv6":false
}
```

I also test in vpn connection in local and change server-ip to local-ip address and run ok with no error

Comment: Where is this open VPN server? It's it at home or in the cloud? Can a Ubuntu client connect?

Comment: its in home, client just connect when i change static ip to local ip and in the same network with server

Comment: Have you set up port forwarding in your home router?